# Buffer I/O errors

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I notice that when I unmount my external HDD I sometimes getting messages in my logs which saying:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sdX, logical block XX
```

Where the X stands for the device for example: sdc. How I seriously do I have to take these messages since the device only spewing this messages when I unmount it, when I mount and use it I don't get any messages and the device works fine at this point as far I can see.

Comment: Hard to know without more information. I suggest you run fsck on the partition(s) and use smartmontools `smartctl -a /dev/sda` or `smartctl -H /dev/sda` change sda to your hard drive

Comment: I have 2 external HDD's. One was able to give me info about the smart. https://www.dropbox.com/s/81nndc10yqy5ux8/smart%20first%20hdd.txt?dl=0

Comment: The one that is giving the messages ? Is it healthy ?

Comment: Those results look alright, see http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl

Comment: The second drive I had to use in Windows and check with CrystalDiskInfo for the smart status. Note that this is a Seagate Disk. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6bj2x4l1epao9z/smart%20hdd%202.png?dl=0

Comment: That one looks alright as well. Both drives have some wear, but there is no indication from smartmontools of imminent failure. Be warned, hard drive failure can occur at any time with no warning. Make backups of your data and continue to monitor the drives from time to time.

Comment: The messages are not always there, I noticed that it only happens when I really write data to both HDD's. When I just plug it in and unmount it doesn't doing this as far as I can see. I use my external HDD's for my virtuel machines and the other is used as a back-up HDD. Also both HDD's are working fine, no hangs or crashes when I use both devices. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Those messages can be normal -

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02270753&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en

https://serverfault.com/questions/613249/buffer-i-o-error-on-device-sata-drive

to impending drive failure (unlikely).

smartmontools is required to determine the health of the drive and your drives passed.

```
smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl -t short /dev/sda
```

to show the results of tests

```
smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```

Example:

> smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
> ...
> Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)
>
> LBA_of_first_error
>
> 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1689         -

You can use fsck to check the file system, but fsck should be run from a live usb.

```
fsck -a -y /dev/sda1
```

the -a and -y options attempt repair.

with fsck you specify a partition.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl

http://www.maketecheasier.com/check-repair-filesystem-fsck-linux/

Comment: You can add -c and it will check for bad blocks as well

Answer (score 3):

I formatted al my external hdd's to a EXT4 filesystem and I didn't see the errors again. Looks like it had something to do with the NTFS driver I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, reformatting solved it for me. I used the `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda` command.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this buffer issues can be indicative of a pending HDD failure. However, it is best to test the drive and verify and see where exactly the error lay. Please run `e2fsck -fv /dev/sdX`. If it runs without error, then there must be something else wrong. If it has any errors or mentions moving sectors, backup immediately and prepare to replace the drive. I recommend replacing it sooner rather than later in that case

Comment: Not necessarily ... they can be "just noise", we need more information.

Comment: Thus the command. Mind you, I have seen drives develop bad sectors and not fail, but these were always laptop drives under heavy use.

Comment: smartmontools are better, IMO, then fsck  to give hard drive health.

Comment: I do like smartmontools, since it is a little faster, but fsck is more thorough.

Comment: fsck checks the file system rather then the hard drive. See http://lpic2.unix.nl/ch04s02.html or similar.